# Oracle Run same procedure concurrently

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to run same procedure with different parameters at same time in oracle.

```
Begin
  exec ProcDeleteA(1);
  exec ProcDeleteA(2);
  exec ProcDeleteA(3);
END;
```

I created procedure ProcDeleteA(tablenumber number). I created 100 temp table 
with each has 5 million orphan ids in it which needs to be deleted from 
production table. Each night , I run for three tables ids which are to be 
deleted from one production table. I want to run same procedure three times 
concurrently, so that three proc run and complete deleting from production 
table by 5 A.M in the morning. Any suggestions to run proc concurrently. The 
temp table numbers are stored in a table. Every day three temp table numbers 
are inserted and those table ids will be deleted from production table.

Please suggest how to run procedure concurrently? Can it be achieved through 
pl/SQL or shell script?

I created 100 temp tables with 5 million records in each of the temp table that needs to be deleted from a table in production. Basically i have primary key (ids) of the production table stored in these temp tables. These are orphan ids that application generated which are Pre identified and stored in these temp tables  and these ids need to be deleted from production table.  so the temp tables are like temptab1, temptab2...temptab100. Basically I want to delete 500 million rows from production table. Everyday I want to run for 3 tables and it will delete the ids from production table. It will take like 30 days to delete 500 million rows. Can't delete during day time and only 15 million per night because the deletions flow through golden gate.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us much about your actual problem, so I don't understand why you need three instances of this procedure. I also don't understand why you can't run them sequentially.

But you can basically do what you're asking by scheduling a job to run at a given time with `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name => 'MYJOB1',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin ProcDeleteA(1); end;',
    start_date => SYSDATE,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY',
    enabled => TRUE );
```

That will run it every day at the current time.

**Edit:** You need something that will start your procedure, then return, but leave it running. This will spawn a process that immediately starts running, but return control to you, then you can run it again for your other procedures. it won't repeat.

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name => 'MYJOB1',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin ProcDeleteA(1); end;',
    start_date => SYSDATE,
    repeat_interval => NULL,
    enabled => TRUE,
    auto_drop => TRUE );
```

Are you starting three different instances of your procedure because you think it will be faster than a single one? Depending on what you're doing, it possibly wont.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't use dbms_scheduler. It has to be through pl/sql or shell script.

Comment: I have window of 11p.m to 5 A.M to delete 15 million records from production table whose primary keys are preidentified and stored in these temp tables.

Comment: dbms_scheduler is pl/sql, so why not? what limitations do you have?

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER is the most appropriate solution to run multiple PL/SQL tasks in a bounded time window. So, you really ought to explain why you need to use a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: I want to run for 3 table numbers every night. I insert every day 3 table numbers in  a table and those 3 table numbers will be run every night. For example. Procdeletetab1, procdeletetab2, procdeletetab3 for tonight per say then tomorrow night will run for procdeletetab4 , procdeletetab5 and procdeletetab6. Need to run this through shell script.

Comment: lead insists on shell script not dbms_scheduler for this process.